# Rx Observable creation / structure

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Can anyone explain what the difference is between the following 2 sources? I came across the first block but not sure why it would be preferable to the second.

**source 1**

```
Observable
    .of(futureDate)
    .flatMap(date => {
        const delay = date - Date.now();
        return Observable.timer(delay);
    });
```

**source 2**

```
const delay = futureDate - Date.now();
Observable.timer(delay);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference becomes apparent when you consider that nothing happens until a subscription is made - and subscriptions could be made sometime after the observables have been created.

When a subscription is made to the first observable, the delay passed to the timer is based upon the current time - that is, the time of subscription.

When a subscription is made the the second, the timer's delay will have been based upon the time at which the observable was created - not upon the time of subscription.

Comment: I wonder if ifs not overkill to use an Observable in the first place seeing as the only subscription is created immediately after the creation of the Observable.. Why not just use a setTimeout?

Comment: I guess it depends on the code base. If observables aren't used to any great extent and the subscription is explicit and immediate, `setTimeout` would likely be simpler. If the code base is observable-based, an observable would probably be preferred. However, in reactive code bases, explicit subscriptions can be considered a code smell.

Comment: With Angular and [NgRx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) or with React and [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) and/or [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#observable-utilities) it's often the case that there are no explicit subscriptions. Observables are composed and the framework manages the subscriptions.